# Is it possible to launch Battlefield 3 or 4 campaign without Battlelog

Tags: battlefield-3, origin, battlefield-4, battlelog

I was wondering whether it is possible to launch the singleplayer campaign for either BF3 or BF4 without the use of the browser. This is useful when:

1. You don't have an internet connection at that moment
2. Battlelog is down.

Comment: If you set Origin to "Offline" and click on the Battlefield 3/4 icon the game should just launch and give you the option of campaign missions.

Comment: I'd be interested in this too. Although I've unistalled the game after playing maybe a third of the game I've found the stupid site especially annoying.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a much easier way, this way origin will still be online so all your save data gets synced as you play. Simply create a shortcut, right click and select properties, select target and write "singleplayer" at the end after \bf3.exe"

[image: example]

Answer (score 10):

I'll post my comment as an answer, just in case.

If you set Origin to "Offline" and click on the Battlefield 3/4 icon the game should just launch and give you the option of campaign missions.

I found this out by mistake once when my Origin was offline and it lauched straight into the campaign. I was mightily confused until I realised it was offline.

Comment: Do you know if it syncs your progress with Battlelog when it is back online?

Comment: @Isaac Yes, when you next open the game with Origin online, you should get a message that it is out of sync, and you need to choose whether to keep local data or cloud data.

Comment: I can't get this to get the play button enabled when offline.